# How to use XML StreamReader in Qt?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, streamreader

i have this XML
located in C:/project/setting.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configs>
  <interval>10</interval>
  <size>176,144</size>
</configs>
```

how to link to my QT project?

and how to call the interval and size value of my XML in my .cpp file?.

thankyou.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Qt examples?](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-streambookmarks-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer working directly with the DOM document directly for reading, and using the streamer only for writing (`QXmlStreamWriter`). Using `QXmlStreamReader` is quite laborious since, for maximum robustness, you have to consider all possibilities for the current position of the reader. If you don't mind changing the reading method you can take a look at this answer.

Qt already provides a [good tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpledommodel-example.html) of how using the DOM document, but here you have a simplified version for your current problem. Just add the XML module to your Qt project.

```
#include <QtXML>

bool readXML(const QString& path)
{
  try {
    QFile inFile(path);
    if (!inFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) return false;

    QDomDocument xml("xml");
    xml.setContent(inFile.readAll());

    auto configs = xml.documentElement();
    if (configs.tagName() != "configs") return false;

    // No error checking nor other type conversion done here
    qDebug() << configs.firstChildElement("interval").firstChild().nodeValue();
    qDebug() << configs.firstChildElement("size").firstChild().nodeValue();
  } catch (...) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

*It doesn't make a rigorous error checking, just two of them as an example. You should always check if your current node actually exists.*

**Important note:** A tricky part of the DOM model is that the actual value of a node like `<interval>10</interval>` is not given by

```
auto interval = configs.firstChildElement("interval");
qDebug() << interval.nodeValue();
```

but by

```
auto interval = configs.firstChildElement("interval");
qDebug() << interval.firstChild().nodeValue();
```

The text node is actually the first child of the `interval` node. Take this in mind.

---

If you want to navigate an XML that contains several elements with the same name at the same level, like

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configs>
  <interval>10</interval>
  <interval>100</interval>
  <interval>1000</interval>
  <size>176,144</size>
</configs>
```

you can use the [`nextSiblingElement`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomnode.html#nextSiblingElement) method to get the next element:

```
for (auto interval = configs.firstChildElement("interval");
     !interval.isNull();
     interval= interval.nextSiblingElement("interval")) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Qt no longer recommends using QtXML. As stated in [the documentation:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html) "The module is not actively maintained anymore. Please use the QXmlStreamReader and QXmlStreamWriter classes in Qt Core instead."

Comment: Interesting note, didn't know about it, it's a shame. Thanks @MrEricSir to point it out!